# Search a file for a number that is between two specific numbers

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

```
$ cat logfile
1;1472223253;frank;12344;1472224386
2;1472223265;andrew;shop;
3;1472225515;frank;12345;1472225531
4;1472225526;joe;12344;1472225534
```

What can I run to get lines that contain numbers between 1472225000 and 1472226000?

```
3;1472225515;frank;12345;1472225531
4;1472225526;joe;12344;1472225534
```

Comment: Does field 5 (if present) qualify as a number to search for? (I assumed field 2).

Comment: I'll get done what I need to just with field 2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F';' '$2 > 1472225000 && $2 < 1472226000' < logfile
```

Tell awk to use semicolons as the field separator (`-F';'` -- the single quotes are to prevent the shell from seeing the semicolon as a command separator; you could use `-F\;`), then select lines where field 2 has values between those you provided. The default action for a line, once selected, is to print it.

Edit to generalize the solution to *any* field qualifying for comparison:

```
awk -F';' '{ 
  flag=0; 
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i > 1472225000 && $i < 1472226000) flag=1; 
  if (flag) print
}' < logfile
```